# How to add a new section to a numbered list in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, numbering

In Word how can I add a section into a numbered list?

I have a large software requirements document that is organized using a numbered list, so I have a few paragraphs as 1, then maybe some sub-points as 1.1, 1.2, 1.3.

I am having trouble where Word is starting a new number and not letting me edit into the current flow of the sequence.

How can I add a new paragraph into a section such as this so that I can add a new paragraph in-between existing ones and have the rest re-numbered?

Comment: "Section" has its own meaning in Word. You likely want to add normal paragraphs that are not numbered, is that true?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of MS Word are we talking about? This would be helpful to know to quote the menu items correctly...

Anyway, try right-clicking on your newly inserted list item (which as I understand at this point has an incorrect number), choose `Numbering > Set Numbering Value` (bottom of the menu). In the pop-up choose `Continue from previous list` and adjust the numbering value if necessary.

As long as you have inserted it in your main list the rest of your existing numbered items will be re-numbered accordingly.

Hopefully, this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you press Enter twice on any numbered line then unnumbered section appears between two continiously numbered lists.

Answer (score 1):

I've just encountered this problem and solved it. I am using **Word 2013**.

The situation was: I had a numbered list with defined styles for heading 1 and heading 2 in order to be able to autogenerate Table of Contents. I had following headings in a multileveled list: 1., 2., 3., 3.1., 3.2., 3.3., 3.4., 4., 4.1., 4.2., 4.3. and I wanted to add heading of level 2 between 3.1 and 3.2. My first try was (as propably everyone would do) to type text and select a list option and hope that it will somehow automatically merge with existing list. It didn't happen, only new list has started.

Solution:

1. Type text wherever you wish to insert a heading of whichever level
2. Select style for typed text for according level (f.ex. "Heading 2")
3. Select multilevel list type (third list-type button in "paragraph" frame) and from scrolldown menu choose the one list in "Lists in current documents" ([see pic.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9mu7.png)). This will sync styles of numbering of new list and existing one.
4. Right-click on the number beside heading (still incorrect) and choose "Continue Numbering". This will add this heading to existing list.